# IIS express error 500.0 every time is run

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express, http-status-code-500

After the Visual Studio 2017 update to the version 15.9.9

Now, every time I start a projects needs IIS Express (I have IIS express 10.0), I got an error.

The error is onyl "HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error" and I don't know where retrieve more info.

I restarted Visual Studio, my pc, deleted the file in the .vs folder of one of my project, executed it as administrator, updated the browser, changed the browser..

in the iis express log, I have this for every request I make

```
2019-03-19 15:34:24 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 54480 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/73.0.3683.75+Safari/537.36 http://localhost:54480/...... 500 0 2148734724 3
```

The error code is 2148734724

What can I do? I also tried to reinstall IIS Express, but probably I'm missing the correct procedure. I downloaded IIS Express from here https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48264 and I got the error message "a newer version is already installed", but it's the same I have on my machine..

In the trace log file I have

```
<failedRequest url="http://localhost:54480/favicon.ico"
               siteId="1"
               appPoolId="IISExpressAppPool"
               processId="876"
               verb="GET"
               authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE"               activityId="{80000005-0001-FA00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="500"
               triggerStatusCode="500"
               timeTaken="0"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-03-19T15:18:38.131Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000005-0001-FA00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="876" ThreadID="7112"/>
  <Computer>IS-WS-ALBERTO</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000005-0001-FA00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="SiteId">1</Data>
  <Data Name="AppPoolId">IISExpressAppPool</Data>
  <Data Name="ConnId">1610612739</Data>
  <Data Name="RawConnId">0</Data>
  <Data Name="RequestURL">http://localhost:54480/favicon.ico</Data>
  <Data Name="RequestVerb">GET</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="it-IT">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_REQUEST_START</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

Please, I really need some help here.

Comment: I uninstalled IIS express and reinstalled again, nothing changed..

Comment: Anything interesting in the NT Event logs?

Comment: 500.0 indicates errors from your web app (likely unhandled exceptions). Go to VS debugging settings and disable Just My Code and then you should be able to stop on the occasion.

Comment: @LexLi I repeat, this happens for ALL my project. Further, the Just My code flag is already disabled...

Comment: "this happens for ALL my project" was the first time you mentioned that, so please edit the question to include that (BTW, "ALL my project" or "ALL my projects"? That can matter a lot). The trace log fragment you cut and pasted does not contain the most important info either, as which module/handler gives you the 500.0 error can tell a lot on what might be wrong. Again, before panic, there is still a lot to be done.

Comment: I meant "ALL my projects", sorry for the typo. So, what can I do? :(